# Insert special characters into Oracle Database via DBLink

Tags: sql, oracle, special-characters

I have a source database from which I insert the data into the target table.
The structure for the both the places is the same.

There is a field as DESCRIPTION and its length is 250, which is same on both the systems.

When i insert into my database, it shows me that the description is 252 characters.
Upon investigation, it showed that there are certain special characters in the source data, which at the time of insertion increases the length.

Is there any way to insert those into the target database as it is from the source?

the query I use is:

```
insert into col1, col2, col3
select col1, col2, col3 from TABLE@DBLINK;
```

Comment: What is the character set of the source and the target database (national character set if you are using `nvarchar2` columns)?  Are you using character or byte length semantics?

Comment: It's varchar2 at both sides.  Using character

Comment: What is the database character set on both sides?  Are you positive that you are using character length semantics in both table definitions?  That's not the default and the vast majority of times that you get the error you appear to be indicating that you're getting, it involves byte length semantics (which is the default).

Comment: Which ones are the special characters ? Have you compared the octet sequences by which the strings are encoded ?